# How can I insert certain python code using VIM input field?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, vim

example:

```
fun! s:MyScript(startline,endline)

python3 << endpython
import vim

startline = vim.eval("a:startline")
endline = vim.eval("a:endline")

for n in range(startline, endline + 1):
    line = vim.current.buffer[n - 1]

#===========================
# start input lines

if re.search(...,line):
   do this or that

# end input lines
#===========================

    vim.current.buffer[n - 1] = line

endpython
endfun
```

I want to insert python code dynamically between start and end input lines in above script.
I know that I can use Vim's input field (`Let question = ....`) to do certain things with "line" p.e. `line = eval(myinputlline)` but how can I insert python code like `if re.search(....)` and more lines at once?

Comment: Save the code to a file and use [`py3file`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html#:py3file).

Comment: @phd`  Hi, You mean all code or only the "input code"?

Comment: Save Python code in a separate (from `vim`) file.

Comment: @phd but what about the vim script? I still don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Instead of `python3 << endpython` you run `py3file file.py`. To change filenames at the execution time use `execute`: `:execute 'py3file ' . filename`.

Comment: @phd but I need the vim code as well. How can I include the vim code in a python script?

Comment: The same way you include it in `python3 << endpython`.

Comment: @phd startline and endline of a visual selection are vim variables that I only can create in vimscript. I need both to execute my script.

Comment: No, they're python variables that the script creates using `import vim`.

Comment: @phd that's what I thought but it doesn't work. `startline = int(vim.eval('line("''<")'))` and `endline = int(vim.eval('line("''>")'))` are always 0 in my script. Something doesn't work.

Comment: This means that the mark `'<` is not defined. It will be defined after you have a selection. You can try this without python at all: first `:echo line("'<")`; then create a visual selection and repeat the expression. First time I got `0`, after having a selection I got the first line of the selection.

Comment: Yes, yes I know but it doesn't work when I launch the script. I selected the lines. Launched the script `py3file path2script`. Printed startline and endline in script: 0 and 0

Comment: @phd Can I ask you one more question? Do you know how to call a menu function from a python script? `vim.command(":call s:myfunction()")` doesn't work. Doesn't accept the "s:" / "<sub>" and I can't change the function name.

Comment: Hmm… I have to think and experiment. `s:` means "from the current script", and switching from vimscript to python could create problems with vim understanding what is "the current script".

Comment: @phd thanks for your help :) There is even another problem. I can't detect if a visual selection is active or normal mode. It always returns a visual selection even if nothing is selected.

Comment: For me all modes are `n` (Normal). Really strange. BTW, all these questions must be separate questions as they are separate topics.

Comment: yes mode() is always 'n' but if I run the script startline and endline is always a selection. I tried to use `:normal \<ESC>` but that doesn't work either. No not separate questions. imo it's still part of my question above. I didn't find the solution to insert python code in my vim function. I don't understand why vim is so complicated. We just need a line "what is the current mode". If selection the current mode is visual, else normal. Vim is a great editor but vimscript is much less usable (logical) than python is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me: file `test-vim.py`:

```
import vim

startline = vim.eval("line(\"'<\")")
endline = vim.eval("line(\"'>\")")

print(startline)
print(endline)
```

I started `vim somefile`. Selected a few lines from 6 to 3. Ran `:py3file test-vim.py`. `vim` reported

```
6
3
```

Comment: Not the answer of my question but I can live with it :) Thanks.